# How can I load an image from a JSON array in this script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, image

I'm trying to figure out how to load an image from the web server for the array "logo" in this JS. Not a big JS wizard and can't work this one out.

The script dynamically populates table cells when detecting the change event "select" and writes those into different columns of the table. Just loading an image beats my head.

The entire code inc the table is up on [myjsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HammerMan/ddXYt/)

```
var data = {
"details":
    {
    "info": [
        {
        "name": "Prod1",
        "logo": "P1 Logo",
        "d1": "Specs of this",
        "d2": "Some Details",
        "d3": "More text about this",
        "d4": "Even more details here",
        "rating": "3 stars"
        },
    {
        "name": "Prod2",
        "logo": "P2 Logo",
        "d1": "Specs here",
        "d2": "Details go here",
        "d3": "wow, more text",
        "d4": "Even more text and details",
        "rating": "1 stars"
        },
    {
        "name": "Prod3",
        "logo": "P3 Logo",
        "d1": "Specs and stuff",
        "d2": "Details or some other things",
        "d3": "More details go here wow",
        "d4": "Almost forgot - more here",
        "rating": "5 stars"
        },
    {
        "name": "Prod4",
        "logo": "P4 Logo",
        "d1": "Specs, stuff etc",
        "d2": "Some other things",
        "d3": "What should I say",
        "d4": "details go here wow",
        "rating": "4 stars"
        }
    ]}
};

$(".select").change(function() {
var jthis = $(this);
var whichCol;
if (jthis.hasClass("col2")) {
    whichCol = "col2";
} else if
    (jthis.hasClass("col3")) {
    whichCol = "col3";
} else if
(jthis.hasClass("col4")) {
    whichCol = "col4";
}
$.each(data.details.info, function(i, v) {
    if (v.name == jthis.val()) {
        $("td." + whichCol + ".name").html(v.name);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".logo").html(v.logo);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d1").html(v.d1);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d2").html(v.d2);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d3").html(v.d3);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d4").html(v.d4);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".rating").html(v.rating);
        return;
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Is the file name of the logo 'P4 Logo' etc., with a space and without an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In json object property logo should represent the url to reqired logo on the server. If you have url you can simply add img tag instead simple text.

Example:

```
$.each(data.details.info, function(i, v) {
if (v.name == jthis.val()) {
    $("td." + whichCol + ".name").html(v.name);
    $("td." + whichCol + ".logo").html("<img src='" + v.logo + "' />");
    $("td." + whichCol + ".d1").html(v.d1);
    $("td." + whichCol + ".d2").html(v.d2);
    $("td." + whichCol + ".d3").html(v.d3);
    $("td." + whichCol + ".d4").html(v.d4);
    $("td." + whichCol + ".rating").html(v.rating);
    return;
}
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddXYt/15/) you can see edited version of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `v.logo` is equal to `path/to/logo.png`, this should work:

```
$.each(data.details.info, function(i, v) {
    if (v.name == jthis.val()) {
        $("td." + whichCol + ".name").html(v.name);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".logo").html('<img src="' + v.logo + '" alt="' + v.name + '" />');
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d1").html(v.d1);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d2").html(v.d2);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d3").html(v.d3);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d4").html(v.d4);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".rating").html(v.rating);
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: that's great but not sure what you mean with /path/to/...? You mean same directory as the java script? can I put a full url in or something like /media/images/chart/xx.jpg?

Comment: @Andy You can put any URL in there. A relative one (`../../images/media/chart/interesting.png`), and an absolute (full) URL: (`http://www.anydomain.com/images/media/chart/interesting.png`). This is also what you have to put as for the `logo` in you JSON.

Comment: that easy right? thanks a lot. Please see my last comment above yours. Maybe you have an idea to that?

Comment: @Andy Why not just give the `td.logo` class in CSS the styling of `text-align: center`? Eg: `<style type="text/css">td.logo { text-align: center; }</style>`

Comment: You're a star! For some reason I didn't think of adding it to the css which is great cause the site has a custom.css I can call from and add the styling to. doesn't show for the logo on [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HammerMan/ddXYt/) but work fine on my localhost. Thank you!

Comment: @Andy It works fine on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddXYt/25/), just don't include any `<style>` tags, as it already knows that it's CSS.

Comment: yepp all works fine now. Already added the chart to the website and tied the css to the custom files same as the array. Works great. thanks again! It's up for anyone who has use for a comparison chart on my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HammerMan/ddXYt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add img element in your logo html

EDIT :

I've done it better like h2ooooooo sugested : http://jsfiddle.net/ddXYt/16/

Comment: All the provided solutisn above work for me. thanks very much to all three of you - Only Q that remains now is how can I center the images in the cell? since td class is already used to identify the td to write the content.